# Creating a ubbi dubbi detector in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make an ubbi dubbi detector in java. I am currently trying to count how many ub's there are in the string and add them up to a counter and then if there is a certain number under the int I put, then it is not ubbi dubbi, but if it is equal to or above then it is ubbi dubbi. We aren't allowed to use regex, string builder, or arrays.

Here is what I have currently:

```
public static boolean detect(String phrase) {
    boolean isUbbi = false;
    int count = 0;
    CharSequence ub = "ub";

    if (phrase.contains(ub)) {
        count++;
    }
    if (count >= 2) {
        isUbbi = true;
    } else {
        isUbbi = false;
    }
    return isUbbi;
}
```

Comment: And your question is what exactly?

Comment: Why is it when I run this I don't get true when I have an ubbi dubbi sentence in the detect?

Comment: Well what prevents you to do a for loop and check the String for occurances of ub?

Comment: Thanks for the help Matthias, just added the for loop and it now works!

Answer (score 1):

In your case it the condition never met to become `true`.

Because

```
if (phrase.contains(ub)) {
        count++;
    }
```

And the condition is

```
 if (count >= 2) {  // never met. Always false.
```

That will check the occurrence once and then done.little more implementation is needed to check no of occurrences which involves a `loop` and `sub-string` etc..

If you are free to use [Apache commons library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

use

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(phrase, "ub");
```

If no  libraries ,

```
        String mainString = "ububsdfub";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("ub");
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(mainString);
        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            count += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(count);  // prints 3 since 3 ub's are there.
```

With basic operation split(internally uses regex)

```
        String mainString = "ububsdfUb";
        String occurance = "ub";
        System.out.println(mainString.split(occurance, -1).length-1);
```

Even split not allowed

```
        String mainString = "ububsdfub";
        String occurance = "ub";
        int index=0;
        int count=0;
        while ((index = mainString.indexOf(occurance, index)) != -1) {
            count++;
            index += occurance.length() - 1;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: We are not allowed to use regex either.

Comment: @itsaferbie Thanksgod :) There is another possibility, Updated.

Comment: `String.split` is using regex internally. This is not an implementation detail but well documented. Some people might regard this as cheating if using regex was forbidding explicitly. Be warned…

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of occurrences by using `String.indexOf(…)`.

```
int count=0;
for(int pos=phrase.indexOf(ub); pos>0; pos=phrase.indexOf(ub, pos)+1) count++;
// now count contains the numbers of occurrences of ub in phrase
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I came up with, just added the for loop and all works.

```
public static boolean detect(String phrase) {
    boolean isUbbi = false;
    int count = 0;
    CharSequence ub = "ub";

    for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        if (phrase.contains(ub)) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count >= 2) {
            isUbbi = true;
        } else {
            isUbbi = false;
        }
    }
    return isUbbi;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `phrase.contains(ub)` would ever return something different when calling it multiple times? What you are doing is equal to: `if(phrase.contains(ub)) count=phrase.length(); else count=0;`